# Medoo | Delete with Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

Hi currently I started to use Medoo, when I checked [documentation](https://medoo.in/api/delete) I couldn't find a way to delete records with inner join statement.

Is there any workaround to delete records with inner join using `$db->delete()` method?

Original SQL Query:

```
DELETE t1 FROM customers t1 INNER JOIN customers t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND (t1.customer_name = t2.customer_name AND t1.customer_unique_code = t2.customer_unique_code)
```

What I tried so far is using inner query like I did in `$db->select` but unfortunately it didn't work.

Currently I am able to work it with `$db->query()` but this is not an optimal solution for me.

```
$db->query(
    'DELETE
        t1 FROM '.$customers_db.' t1 INNER JOIN '.$customers_db.' t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND(
            t1.customer_name = t2.customer_name AND t1.customer_unique_code = t2.customer_unique_code)
');
```

I would like to know whether there is a better approach than this.

Thanks in advance for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it in query but doing it with concatenation like that is not the best way to do it. Try using parametrisation like this:

```
$db->query(
    'DELETE t1
        FROM :custdb t1
        INNER JOIN :custdb t2
        WHERE t1.id < t2.id
            AND (
                t1.customer_name = t2.customer_name AND t1.customer_unique_code = t2.customer_unique_code
            )',
    [
        ":custdb" => "customer_DB_name"
    ]
);
```

I do not know how to do a join with a delete (I doubt it is possible) however, if you create the view you want in your database itself, then you could select the view in the delete statement without an issue.